# My itertools product method is not working? Why?

Tags: python, permutation, product, python-itertools

I'm working with itertools product and trying to return possible permutations.
This is what I'm trying to pass:

```
from itertools import product

df = {'A':[0,0.03,0.5],
     'B':[0,0.02,0.5],
     'C':[0,0.015,0.03],
     'D':[0,0.15,0.3],
     'E':[0,0.1,0.4],
     'F':[0,0.06,0.5],
     'G':[0,0.07,0.5]}

for element in product(list(df.values())):
   print(element)
```

What I get back:

```
([0, 0.03, 0.5],)
([0, 0.02, 0.5],)
([0, 0.015, 0.03],)
([0, 0.15, 0.3],)
([0, 0.1, 0.4],)
([0, 0.06, 0.5],)
([0, 0.07, 0.5],)
```

What I want:
All possible permutations of the numbers, one possible solution would look like:

```
[0,0.02,0.015,0.15,0.4,0.06,0.07]
```

Why is the product method not working as desired. Working out of Jupyter Notebooks - Python 3.

Comment: You need to flatten the list before taking product.

Comment: Because you are providing a single iterable to `product`.

Comment: Please closely look at the [documentation for itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). Each of your columns should be a separate argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
from itertools import product

df = {'A':[0,0.03,0.5],
     'B':[0,0.02,0.5],
     'C':[0,0.015,0.03],
     'D':[0,0.15,0.3],
     'E':[0,0.1,0.4],
     'F':[0,0.06,0.5],
     'G':[0,0.07,0.5]}
for element in product(*df.values()):
   print(element)
```

example output:

```
...
(0.5, 0.5, 0.03, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0)
(0.5, 0.5, 0.03, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.07)
(0.5, 0.5, 0.03, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5)
(0.5, 0.5, 0.03, 0.3, 0.4, 0, 0)
(0.5, 0.5, 0.03, 0.3, 0.4, 0, 0.07)
(0.5, 0.5, 0.03, 0.3, 0.4, 0, 0.5)
(0.5, 0.5, 0.03, 0.3, 0.4, 0.06, 0)
(0.5, 0.5, 0.03, 0.3, 0.4, 0.06, 0.07)
(0.5, 0.5, 0.03, 0.3, 0.4, 0.06, 0.5)
(0.5, 0.5, 0.03, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0)
(0.5, 0.5, 0.03, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.07)
(0.5, 0.5, 0.03, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5)
```

Comment: Please educate me on this. What does the " * " do since that's the only thing I seemed to be missing? Just trying to learn and get better. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @datalover_Pk1 it's called unpacking.  It's most common use is maybe as `*args` and `**kwargs`, you can read about it here: https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/

Answer (score 0):

You need to flatten the list as below:

```
for element in product([item for data in df.values() for item in data)):
   print(element)
```